# How to obtain size of BLOB without reading BLOB's content?

Tags: jpa, blob, eclipselink

I want to show a list of file names read from a database and their sizes, but if I read the value of the blob the query is very slow. How I can calculate the size of the blob without reading it?

I'm using EclipseLink.

Comment: You can do what Mikko suggested below, but imho, I think store the blob size in separate field is a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a facility in JPQL. Also how it is done with native query probably depends about the database. At least with MySQL and Oracle following works:

```
SELECT LENGTH(blob_field) FROM table_name;
```

If you use JPQL, `LENGTH` function is limited to character types, so it is not applicable for `BLOB`. Of course there can be persistence provider extension which makes it work.

Answer (score 0):

JPQL supports LENGTH, so this should also work in JPQL,

```
Select LENGTH(o.blobField) from MyObject o
```

Otherwise you could always use FUNC in JPQL,

```
Select FUNC('LENGTH', o.blobField) from MyObject o
```